Kafka Message Delivery in Spring Integration Application With Spring Cloud Stream
I have a Spring Integration application, and I want to add functionality to send messages to Kafka after successful processing. Here's what I have written:
@Bean
  public Supplier<Message<?>> myFunction(QueueChannel kafkaMessageChannel) {
    return kafkaMessageChannel::receive;
  }

  @Bean(name = KAFKA_CHANNEL)
  MessageChannel kafkaMessageChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.queue().get();
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow1() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(SOME_CHANNEL)
        .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO)
        .transform(// transformer)
        .channel(KAFKA_CHANNEL)
        .get();
  }

  spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: myFunction
    stream:
      default-binder: kafka
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: ${BROKERS}
        bindings:
          myFunction-out-0:
            producer:
              configuration:
                key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      bindings:
        myFunction-out-0:
          destination: myDestination
          binder: kafka
          content-type: application/json
          producer:
            error-channel-enabled: true
            use-native-encoding: true

The message gets to the transformer, where the message gets logged, but it never appears in the Kafka topic.
Are there any suggestions on what could be going wrong and how to fix it? Thanks.
NOTE! One observation: I have multiple functions associated with different bindings that I haven't mentioned here. The interesting part is that when I run it like this:
function:
  definition:aFunction;bFunction;cFunction;dFunction;myFunction

myFunction doesn't work..
But if I list myFunction as the first element, everything works perfectly.
Update: I have changed all the suppliers from channelName::receive to () -> channelName.receive(1), and it fixed the problem.

Good to see that you have figured out something for your application. And what exactly is the question right now? Would you mind to playing with a spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=10 property to have more threads for scheduling? Feels like your application is a bit complicated and deals with a number of QueueChannel instances.
